# How can you set an app to be removed from the Dock when closed?

Tags: applications, dock

Apps, that aren't in the Dock are added to its right when opened. My problem: When those apps are closed, they sometimes remain at the right and take away space!

[image]

That's especially annoying with Apps like QuickView which I'd never open from the Dock (but only when opening files)

Is there an option for this somewhere in the settings?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **System Preferences > Dock & Menu Bar**, uncheck "Show recent applications in Dock"
[image: Screenshot of System Preferences: Dock & Menu Bar settings]

Comment: Could have thought of that on my own ‍♂️ Thank you!