# Why are there two dividers in my dock?

Tags: macos, dock

I've just updated to macOS 12.1 and I found my dock has two dividers where before there was only one. I also see the Firefox logo repeated, which is strange. I can drag icons from the middle section into the left-hand section, but not back.

[image: mac os dock]

same thing in my other user account

[image: another mac os dock]

Both dividers work as normal for resizing.

I'm logged in with two user accounts, if that's relevant.

Is this a bug? Obscure feature?

Comment: Seen this? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/435819/how-can-you-set-an-app-to-be-removed-from-the-dock-when-closed/435820#435820

Comment: Yes, nearly. Doesn't explain why there are two firefoxes, but that wasn't my main question.